# How to get offset range to work in formula?

Tags: excel, vba

I'm having trouble getting an offset range into a formula. The idea is to have a user input the text they want to search for in a string, the value if found, and the value if not found. And then turn all of that into a formula that gets inserted in the selected cell in the active sheet. The problem is that the formula returns the value of SearchCell and not the range.

How can I put the range of SearchCell in the formula and not the value of SearchCell?

```
Sub SearchString()


Dim SelectedCell    As Range
Dim SearchCell      As Range
Dim SearchValue     As Variant
Dim FoundValue      As Variant
Dim NotFoundValue   As Variant


Set SelectedCell = Application.Selection
Set SearchCell = SelectedCell.Offset(, -1)

SearchValue = InputBox("What do you want to search for?")
FoundValue = InputBox("If found?")
NotFoundValue = InputBox("If not found?")

SelectedCell.Formula = "=IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(""*" & SearchValue & "*""," & SearchCell & ")), _
""" & FoundValue & """, """ & NotFoundValue & """)"


End Sub
```

Comment: `SearchCell.Address`

Comment: Getting closer. That puts in a locked address ($G$2). How do I get it to G2?

Comment: Google `Range.Address` it will tell you.

Comment: Teach a man to fish, huh? Thanks buddy, for the quick reply. Googled it and found: SearchCell.Address(RowAbsolute:=False, ColumnAbsolute:=False)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SearchCell.Address(RowAbsolute:=False, ColumnAbsolute:=False)
```